# SQL if query functionality

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a query to determine the success rate for every day for each different mode. I did write a query that'll just group by date and mode which serves my purpose but one of my seniors wrote this following query which also works but I am just unable to understand how the if clause is working. I'll add a bit of the query here -

```
SELECT 
        dt,
        sum(if(mode='A',success,0))AS a_s,
        sum(if(mode='A',total,0))AS a_t,    
        sum(if(mode='B',success,0))AS b_s,
        sum(if(mode='B',total,0))AS b_t,
        sum(if(mode='C',success,0))AS c_s,
        sum(if(mode='C',total,0))AS c_t,
        sum(if(mode='D',success,0))AS d_s,
        sum(if(mode='D',total,0))AS d_t,
        sum(if(mode NOT in('A','B','C','D'),success,0))AS other_s,
        sum(if(mode NOT in('A','B','C','D'),total,0))AS other_t 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            mode,
            date(addedon)AS dt,
            sum(if(status in('success','partial'),1,0))AS success,
            count(*)AS total 
        FROM `a_huge_ass_table` 
        WHERE `studentid`=159633 AND addedon>'2021-01-15' 
        GROUP BY mode,date(addedon)
        )AS t
```

Here I am unable to understand how `sum(if(mode='A',success,0))AS a_s,` - this if clause is working. If the condition is true then the clause is returning success? how does that work does adding success also somehow verify that its status is a success case? I cant find this on google.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `if()` is not standard SQL.  I recommend rewrite this using `case`:

```
    sum(case when mode = 'A' then success else 0 end) as a_s,
    sum(case when mode = 'A' then total else 0 end) as a_t,
```

and so on.

Second, this query is missing the final `group by dt`.  Otherwise it produces one row, rather than a separate row for each `dt` value.

This is called *conditional aggregation*.  Every row in the final result set represents a group of rows from the subquery.  Within this group, some have `mode = 'A'` and some do not.  For the ones with `mode = 'A'` the above sums the value of `success` and `total`.

There is no need for a subquery by the way.  That just slows down the query.  I would recommend writing the query as:

```
SELECT date(addedon) as dt
       SUM( mode = 'A' AND status IN ('success', 'partial') ) as a_success,
       SUM( mode = 'A'  ) as a_total,
       . .  .
FROM `a_huge_ass_table` 
WHERE studentid = 159633 AND addedon >= '2021-01-15' 
GROUP BY date(addedon);
```

Note that this uses a MySQL extension where boolean expressions are treated as integers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

Comment: yes it needs a final group by dt I did not post the whole thing. And yes sub query is redundant here I just didn't understand the if clause functionality. Thank you very much I'll look into conditional aggregation. Also, your query with boolean looks far cleaner and faster. Thanks again.